# Request service name via TCP socket

Tags: php, sockets

I'm making a simple port scanner in PHP, and am trying to figure out how I'd request the name of the service I'm connecting to, similar to how Nmap is able to discover services.

I'm using fsockopen() to open the socket, so I'd use `fwrite($socket, "WHAT SERVICE AM I COMMUNICATING WITH?")` to ask the question, then listen using `fgets($socket)`.

How do I ask the service what it is?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard coded into the program what the different ports are for.  The remote applications don't report them.  There are tons of lists on the internet that provide this information.

Same thing for looking at standard services and responses from similar services on different OSs.  That's how nmap guesses what OS it's talking to.

[Here](http://bandwidthcontroller.com/applicationPorts.html) is a decent starting point.

[Here](https://svn.nmap.org/nmap/nmap-services) is the source file with the port mappings for nmap.

The scary part is the code that tells which versions and such is running.  That's [here](https://svn.nmap.org/nmap/nmap-service-probes) and I'm glad I don't have to write this :\

Last one, pretty sure this is the file that says how to guess which OS a remote computer is:  [here](https://svn.nmap.org/nmap/nmap-os-db)

Comment: Yeah, I just found the page in which the Nmap devs describe their method of scanning for services (http://nmap.org/book/vscan-technique.html); it sounds pretty difficult to replicate. I might decide to forgo this feature, I was just writing this for fun. Worth a try though, thank you! I wish there were just a standard "version" command that all programs knew.

Comment: @user2120415 just checking to see if there's an open TCP port is really easy and you can make naive assumptions like if 22 is accepting connections then SSH is running on the server.  Port 80?  HTTP, etc.  You don't have to report on versions and such.